# SurveyMonkey OAuth - is callback necessary?

Tags: oauth, surveymonkey

Sorry if this is a duplicate Q, I've searched StackOverflow and couldn't find the answer to this (very basic) question.

We're just getting started with OAuth, and trying to create a simple test app to call the SurveyMonkey API. In the examples I've seen, in order to initially generate the access token, you need to call the OAuth API with a 'redirect_uri'. You retrieve the response from OAuth by handling the callback and parsing the parameters on the url.

So the question is, is this the ONLY way to generate the access token? This technique is going to be a problem for us, as we don't really have a suitable public facing web server.

*(as a side note, I've also tried playing with the API console, but I can't get this working either... after hitting "try it", I just see a "Loading..." message without ever getting any sort of response).*

Answer (score 1):

For applications which will not interact with users and which will only access your own SurveyMonkey account, using the API console to get your access token is the currently preferred method. The API will eventually support accessing your own SurveyMonkey account with a simple username and password which will make the whole process possible programmatically.

Even using the API console, you must specify a callback URI for redirect_uri. As sysmod mentioned, your redirect_uri could be localhost or any other valid URI. When using the API console, no callback will actually arrive at the target URI.

To use the API console to get a long-lived access token, click on "Custom Application" under "Application" and enter your API key, client ID (API user name), and client secret. Then click on "Get Access Token". You will be presented with an opportunity to authorize access from your API account to your SurveyMonkey account. Once you've done that, the access token will be displayed and you can copy and paste it into your code.

Having that access token displayed is necessary for the "Try It" button to work.

Comment: Thanks Tony, it makes sense to me now. I used the console to generate the token as you suggest, and have now got a few basic API calls working from my dev environment! (the examples in the api console still don't work for me, but that's really a moot point now).

Answer (score 0):

You can use
    http:// localhost
as the redirect URI.
And use the API Console for testing, although I don't know why you have the error.
If it helps, I've just started at this and have put up some really basic notes at [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cgeesslpcxs7q63/Getting%20Started%20with%20Surveymonkey%20API_docx.pdf).

Comment: Thanks so much, that makes sense. I have now got this working using essentially a dummy redirect URI as you suggest. Thanks also for the link to your docs.

Comment: This works as long as your app doesn't need a Redirect URI.  I used `http://localhost` with no problem.